# .post() failure callback function?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

In the [documentation for the .post() method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), there's a callback function for when the request is successful, but is there a similar method to tell if the request was a failure?

Comment: If you read a little bit further: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) which is a utility function built on top of [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) returns a [promise object](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/) which has a [fail](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) handler that can used to handle failure cases

```
$.post(url, yourdata, function(){
    //success handler
}).fail(function(){
    //fail handler
}).done(function(){
   //more success handlers if you want
})
```

Comment: Where do I specify the data parameter? (The data to post)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use `.fail`:

```
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
})
.fail(function() { 
    alert("error"); 
})
```